# Writing a SQL Query to a .txt file

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

My Query works without the last line,

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE ...
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Public\homework3\1Results.txt';
```

But when run with the "INTO OUTFILE" I'm getting...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 4:  INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Public\homework3\1Results.txt';
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 49
```

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally left a `;` on the end of the `SELECT`? Without seeing the whole query it's impossible to know what is causing the problem.

Comment: The only ; is at the very end, it's SELECT...\n FROM... \n WHERE ...\n INTO ...;

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to a MySQL database? That doesn't look like a MySQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think your INTO statement is in the wrong place and your syntax may be a bit off.  Here's an example:

```
  SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM my_table;
```

Here's some documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: The documentation you linked clearly shows that `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` is a valid form for the query.

Comment: @Nick, you're correct.  I've only used this syntax in the manner that I referenced.  The only other thing I can think of that would be the issue is user is lacking a database server privilege or database server version.